# A four digit year could not be found Data missing save condition

Tags: php, laravel

This is my start_date field format in my interview form "YYYY-MM-DD".

the issue is I can't save when I didn't fill start_date field.

here's my savehandler code so far :

```
public function saveHandler(Request $request, $obj)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $obj->fill($request->all());
        $obj->start_date = isset($interviewTracks['start_date']) ? $interviewTracks['start_date'] : 'YYYY-MM-DD';
        if (!$obj->save()) {
            throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
        }
            foreach($request->interviewTracks as $interviewTracks) {
                if (empty($interviewTracks['id'])) {
                    $interviewTracks = new InterviewTrack();
                }
                else {
                    $interviewTracks = InterviewTrack::find($interviewTracks['id']);
                }
                $interviewTracks->interview()->associate($obj);
                $interviewTracks['interview_id'] = isset($interviewTracks['interview_id']);
                $interviewTracks->status = $interviewTracks['status'];
                $interviewTracks->track_date = isset($interviewTracks['track_date']) ? $interviewTracks['track_date'] : 'YYYY-MM-DD';
                $interviewTracks->outcome = $interviewTracks['outcome'];
                $interviewTracks->remarks = $interviewTracks['remarks'];
                $interviewTracks->save();
            };
            if (!$interviewTracks->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($interviewTracks->errors());
            }

        DB::commit();
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->errors);
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, $e->errors);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request,'Unable to process. Please contact system Administrator');
    }

}
```

any idea ?

Comment: I suppose that your start_date in database is of type 'DATE', but when you do not fill the date you try to insert a string `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: there will be no problem if start_date field in your database is a string. what column type is your field ?

Comment: @AbdouTahiri Date type

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanuis yes its a DATE type,is there any way to "trick" it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your `start_date` column to `nullable()` by default, so if you want to leave the start_date, then you can leave it and the Eloquent will automatically fill null there. Use this in your migrations to set it to nullable...

```
// Example - Just for Demo
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->date('start_date')->nullable(); // <-------- This field sets to nullable by default
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: except using migration and set it to nullable, is there any way to "trick" it ?

Comment: @AndrewVanusi - I think you can't, rather you could enter `0000-00-00` and in your logic treat this as an empty date. Should try this for once.

Answer (score 0):

By default Laravel 5.3 uses strict mode for MySQL.

If you would like to revert this behavior, then update your `config/database.php` file and set

```
'strict' => false
```